# Apscheduler Jobs Process Details

Tags: python-3.x, linux, process, python-asyncio, apscheduler

I have known `Python Apscheduler` schedules Python code to be executed later but one of my senior says you can get the process associated with jobs by using some functions of `apscheduler`.

Is it possible?? like when we do `ps -e` in terminal, it gives a list of processes running. so if i schedule a `pinparsing` command from `apscheduler` it will generate a process. Can I get this process details by `apscheduler` library?

Can anyone help me with the code??

PS : I can get the scheduled jobs using `get_jobs()` but this is a job and not process.

Comment: I am not sure whoever you talked to was 100% correct. If you look at the API Reference for `APScheduler` there is no public way to get this data. Also which executor are you using, the `asyncio` one?

Comment: Yes asyncio scheduler is being used @gold_cy

Comment: Aside from getting the state of `asyncio.Task` in the current event loop there is no other way to see the "processes" running, I am not sure why you were told this is readily possible within the context of this library.

Comment: hi @gold_cy can you atleast give me the code of how to get the Task from the current event loop. I am no where getting close to it. its been 4 days. can you help with the code?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#introspection